# Passing Variable Between Classes

Tags: java, variables

I am trying to pass a string, generated by a JFileChooser between classes. The other part of my program works fine. If I locally define the file path as a string it runs great.

I *think* I need to implement code like this, which works fine in this simple example, but that I can't get to work with code posted further below.

```
public class A {
private static final String x = "This is X";
public static String getX() { return x;}
}

public class B {
public static void main(String args[]) {
String x = A.get();
System.out.println("x = " + x);}
}
```

My full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileChooser extends JFrame {


    public FileChooser() {
        super("File Chooser Test Frame");
        setSize(350, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton openButton = new JButton("Open");
        JButton goButton = new JButton("Go");
        final JLabel statusbar = new JLabel(
                "Output of your selection will go here");

        openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(FileChooser.this);
                if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File[] sf = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
                    String filelist = "nothing";
                    if (sf.length > 0)
                        filelist = sf[0].getName();
                    for (int i = 1; i < sf.length; i++) {
                        filelist += ", " + sf[i].getName();
                    }
                    statusbar.setText(filelist);
                    String thefilename = filelist;

                } else {
                    statusbar.setText("You canceled.");
                }
            }
        });

        goButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                String filepath = statusbar.getText();
                System.out.println(filepath);
            }
        });

        c.add(openButton);
        c.add(goButton);
        c.add(statusbar);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FileChooser sfc = new FileChooser();
        sfc.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `String thefilename = filelist;` is unnecessary.  But for the rest:  What exactly does not work?

Comment: I'm trying to access String the filename from another .java file within the same project, but can't call it via any technique I've found. I'll edit the original question to remove the superfluous line String thefilename = filelist;

Comment: Ah, okay. I’ll write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need `String filelist` in another class, make it an instance variable and add a getter method.

```
public class FileChooser extends JFrame {
  private String filelist;
  // ... initialize string in constructor ..
  public String getFilelist() {
    return filelist;
  }
}
```